# How to implement INTERSECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

This is my current query. I found out about INTERSECT today, however, it's not supported by MySQL. Could anyone give me some advice as to how to improve this query? It gives me the results I'm looking for, but rather slowly.

If it helps, I'm working with sports teams, and filtering for the stats. I filter for the home team, then the away team. I used the count(id) method as I only want to return the fixture IDs that have been found in **both** queries, so I think the INTERSECT would have been perfect.

```
    select id, count(id) as count from (
    
    select f.id, f.etc, etc
    from fixtures f
    inner join team_stats t on f.id = t.fixture_id and f.league_id = t.league_id and f.home_id = t.team_id
    where f.status in ('FT', 'AET', 'PEN', 'FT_PEN') and
    unix < 1619927451 and
    played_overall between '11' and '60' and
    scored_1h_home_avg between '0.7' and '6' and 
    o05_1h_goals_overall_per between '76' and '100' and 
    first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35' and 
    scored_o05_1h_home_per >= 69
    
    UNION ALL
    
    select f.id, f.etc, etc
    from fixtures f
    inner join team_stats t on f.id = t.fixture_id and f.league_id = t.league_id and f.away_id = t.team_id
    where f.status in ('FT', 'AET', 'PEN', 'FT_PEN') and
    unix < 1619927451 and
    played_overall between '11' and '60' and
    conceded_1h_away_avg between '0.7' and '6' and 
    first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35' and 
    o05_1h_goals_away_per between '77' and '100'
)    
    x group by id HAVING count(id) > 1
```

Comment: Be wary of treating integers as strings; under certain circumstances, the results might not be what you would expect: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g7stKibxTZjW9ikroqCeX9/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to get what you want:

```
select f.id
from fixtures f
inner join team_stats t on f.id = t.fixture_id and f.league_id = t.league_id and f.home_id = t.team_id
where f.status in ('FT', 'AET', 'PEN', 'FT_PEN') and
unix < 1619927451 and
played_overall between '11' and '60' and scored_1h_home_avg between '0.7' and '6' and o05_1h_goals_overall_per between '76' and '100' and first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35' and scored_o05_1h_home_per >= 69

and exists(

select 1
from fixtures f2
inner join team_stats t on f2.id = t.fixture_id and f2.league_id = t.league_id and f2.away_id = t.team_id
where f2.status in ('FT', 'AET', 'PEN', 'FT_PEN') and
unix < 1619927451 and
played_overall between '11' and '60' and
conceded_1h_away_avg between '0.7' and '6' and first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35' and o05_1h_goals_away_per between '77' and '100'
and f1.id=f2.id)
```

Another variation can be combining of both queries without `union all`. If your query is producing correct answer then this should also do that.

```
select id, count(id) as i_count 
from fixtures f
inner join team_stats t on f.id = t.fixture_id and f.league_id = t.league_id 
where f.status in ('FT', 'AET', 'PEN', 'FT_PEN') and
unix < 1619927451 and
played_overall between '11' and '60'    

and ((f.home_id = t.team_id and and scored_1h_home_avg between '0.7' and '6'  o05_1h_goals_overall_per between '76' and '100' and first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35' and scored_o05_1h_home_per >= 69)
or (f.away_id = t.team_id and conceded_1h_away_avg between '0.7' and '6' and first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35' and o05_1h_goals_away_per between '77' and '100'))

group by id HAVING count(id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for these. I have found that the UNION ALL with finding the duplicate IDs using PHP is actually much quicker. Is that common? I thought direct with SQL would be.

Answer (score 0):

If I am following correctly, the same is common in both queries:

```
select f.id, f.etc, etc
from fixtures f join
     team_stats t
     on f.id = t.fixture_id and f.league_id = t.league_id and f.away_id = t.team_id
where f.status in ('FT', 'AET', 'PEN', 'FT_PEN') and
      unix < 1619927451 and
      played_overall between '11' and '60' and
      conceded_1h_away_avg between '0.7' and '6' and 
      first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35'
```

Then you want both these conditions:

```
scored_o05_1h_home_per >= 69
o05_1h_goals_away_per between '77' and '100'
```

If so, aggregation is probably the simplest solution:

```
select f.id, f.etc, etc
from fixtures f join
     team_stats t
     on f.id = t.fixture_id and f.league_id = t.league_id and f.away_id = t.team_id
where f.status in ('FT', 'AET', 'PEN', 'FT_PEN') and
      unix < 1619927451 and
      played_overall between '11' and '60' and
      conceded_1h_away_avg between '0.7' and '6' and 
      first_goal_total_avg between '0' and '35'
group by f.id
having sum(scored_o05_1h_home_per >= 69) > 0 and
       sum(o05_1h_goals_away_per between '77' and '100')
```

I also note that you are using single quotes around what look like numbers.  If these are really numbers, then drop the single quotes.  Don't mix types.  If the values are stored as strings, then the comparisons are as strings, not numbers, and may not do what you expect.